# Is there a good way to write "wait for variables to change" in Dart's async method?

Tags: dart

I wrote a program in Dartlang that stops processing until the variable `foo` becomes false as shown below.
It is executable, but continuing to return Future in a while statement is clumsy.
Is there a way to write it clearly?

```
  Future asyncMethod() async {

      while (foo) {
        await new Future(() {
          return null;
        });
      }
```

Unity's coroutine can be written in a single line as below, so I'd like to make this much clearer.

```
yield return new WaitWhile(() => foo);
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are polling the variable at intervals using a timer. There are lots of ways to do that. I'd just go for the completely straight-forward implementation:

```dart
Future waitWhile(bool test(), [Duration pollInterval = Duration.zero]) {
  var completer = new Completer();
  check() {
    if (!test()) {
      completer.complete();
    } else {
      new Timer(pollInterval, check);
    }
  }
  check();
  return completer.future;
}
```

With that function, you can then just write

```dart
await waitWhile(() => foo);
```

to wait for `foo` to become false.

Comment: The worse thing now is choose the interval :C

Answer (score 11):

By using `Future.doWhile`.

**Without** a polling interval:

```dart
await Future.doWhile(() => isPaused);
```

**With** a polling interval:

```dart
if (isPaused) {
  await Future.doWhile(() => Future.delayed(interval).then((_) => isPaused));
}
```